# Limit results of the entity reference

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I have been trying to find the solution to this problem. I am referencing a serial of nodes with entity reference, but I just want to display the latest 3 nodes. Is there any way I can limit the results of the entity reference? I need to have unlimited Number of values but just need to display the last 3 for that case. I am not using views.

I am using Drupal 7

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@junedkazi your point is valid. However, a more flexible solution is to install Display Suite so you can control and limit the number of items on a multiple value field, and works also with entity reference.

There is an extra textfield on the manage display screens to limit the output per field instead of # (to show them all) you can write the number of the items that you would like to display.

I have attached a video that explains better the solution. It is necessary to active the extras that comes with Display Suite in modules administration.

[Limiting the number of fields](http://realize.be/limit-number-fields-display-field-ui-display-suite)

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the Views: Filter by an entity reference view option from Entity selection mode and then create a view and set the number of items to 3.